# Create a unit test two check if two psql schema are the same

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, unit-testing

I have this project with an huge db schema, that sometimes is updated.

So I have a file, called `schema.sql`, which has the current schema, and a directory with all the patches I deploy over time (called like `patches/20160710.sql`, with a file with the first schema called `origin.sql`).

If I do a fresh installation, I use `schema.sql`, otherwise I apply the patch when I do an update.

I have test server where I do tests before updating schema in production and I've automated almost everything. So far works good.

Unfortunately once I wrote a different thing go `schema.sql` and in the patch. My unit test runs only against a fresh database, so tests didn't fail and I found the error only I tried on the test server the patch.

I would like to write an unit test which takes `schema.sql`, deploy it, and compare the schema with the schema generated by all patches applied on `origin.sql`.

I need also the check some tables have the same values.

Database is postgresql and software is in node.js.

Tests are run by Gitlab CI with a custom docker image, so I really can do the test in whatever language is better.

Both patches and `schema.sql` have, of course, the same name for database, so I thought I have to apply `schema.sql`, dump it in some way, then drop the database and recreate it from patches, dump it again and compare the results.

Does this approach make any sense or there is a better way to achieve what I'm doing?

If this makes sense, what's a good way to dump the two databases and compare them?

Comment: Command line for Linux `pg_dump <connection params 1> --schema=<schema to compare> --schema-only > foo1.sql && pg_dump <connection params 2> --schema=<schema to compare> --schema-only > foo2.sql && diff foo1.sql foo2.sql`. If output is empty then schemes are identical. Almost same to compare the data: `psql <connection params 1> -c "<query>" > data1.txt && psql <connection params 2> -c "<query>" > data2.txt && diff data1.txt data2.txt`.

Comment: @Abelisto thanks for the hint. What about the fact two schema have the same name? Is good practice to write a bash script which change the name of the second schema in the test environment?

Comment: As you mention it was just a hint. It is up to you how to use it. In any case I believe that you can do almost anything using bash and PostgreSQL command-line tools.

Comment: @Abelisto thanks so much for your hints, I created an ugly script that works - I posted as answer, feel free to improve it :)

Comment: I am definitely not a bash-guru :o) Looking to your answer you are more experienced with it then I am. Let's say: we should to remember and think about **whole** set of tools what we have. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593144/abelisto)'s hint I made a script similar to this one (my bash-fu is not so good, so feel free to improve it):

```
#!/bin/bash
ORIGINAL_DB="tmp1"
INCREMENTAL_DB="tmp2"
SCHEMA="schema"

function clean_up {
  sudo -u postgres dropdb ORIGINAL_DB
  sudo -u postgres dropdb INCREMENTAL_DB
  sudo -u postgres createdb ORIGINAL_DB
  sudo -u postgres createdb INCREMENTAL_DB
}

function import_schemas {
  sudo -u postgres psql ORIGINAL_DB < database/sql/schema.sql

  for f in database/sql/patches/*.sql ; do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
    sudo -u postgres psql INCREMENTAL_DB < $f
  done
}

function compare_schemas {
  sudo -u postgres pg_dump ORIGINAL_DB --schema=SCHEMA --schema-only > foo1.sql
  sudo -u postgres pg_dump INCREMENTAL_DB --schema=SCHEMA --schema-only > foo2.sql
  line_diff=$(diff foo1.sql foo2.sql | egrep '^<|>' | wc -l)

  if [ $line_diff -ne 0 ]
  then
    diff foo1.sql foo2.sql
    exit -1
  fi
}

function compare_values {
  sudo -u postgres psql ORIGINAL_DB -c "SELECT * FROM roles_permissions ORDER BY idrole, idpermission;" > data1.txt
  sudo -u postgres psql INCREMENTAL_DB -c "SELECT * FROM roles_permissions ORDER BY idrole, idpermission;" > data2.txt

  line_diff=$(diff data1.txt data2.txt | egrep '^<|>' | wc -l)

  if [ $line_diff -ne 0 ]
  then
    exit -1
  fi
}

clean_up
import_schemas
compare_schemas
compare_values

exit 0
```